# How to not vertically overflow table cells and print the table?

Tags: css, html, html-table, overflow

I know there are a lot of questions about that, but none of their solutions worked for me.

I have an html page formed by only a table (that I want print), I want the table to perfectly fit inside an horizontal a4 sheet.

This is my table without text (is a match referee):

[image: myTable]
<sub>(source: [i.ibb.co](https://i.ibb.co/BZnw5wG/Schermata-2019-01-14-alle-13-02-20.png))</sub>

The problem is that when I add some text the height changes.

I tried adding *div* inside *td* with an height, but this doesn't work well...

Also I would like to know how to print the page horizontally, cause my table overflow the printing area...

This is an example of my table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>BLABLABLA</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  ...
  ...
  ...
</table>
```

Comment: How do you want your table to react, if the content doesn't fit - if the table would get bigger than the sheet?
Where is your CSS code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use `table-layout: fixed` to manage size of your table and cells. Then as shown in example below manage overflows.
Which gives you stretched table, which wont adapt height to content.

```css
.myTable {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.myTable tr td div{
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  height: 20px;
}

.myTable tr.higher td div {
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<table class="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td><div>A lot of text to display.A lot of text to display.A lot of text to display.A lot of text to display.A lot of text to display.A lot of text to display.</div></td>
  <td><div>A lot of text to display. A lot of text to display. A lot of text to display.</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="higher">
    <td><div>A lot of text to display. A lot of text to display. A lot of text to display.</div></td>
    <td><div>A lot of text to display. A lot of text to display.</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can insert it into `@media print` and adjust properly to your table.

References:

- [Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp)
- [Position Fixed](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_table-layout.asp)

Comment: The problem is that I don't want the height adapt based on contents.

Comment: So it wont adapt:)

Comment: @LorenzoFiamingo please mark my question if it is ok with u.